Pancakeswap trading bot
I am writing a Pancakeswap trading bot using Python web3 library, but when I run the code it “I cannot output (Tx Hash) when printing” even though there are no errors

note: private_key is run as a separate file as a package. In the first file, code sections that will help run the project are written.
In the second file, there should be a file with your 12-digit secret password for the wallet you want to connect to the bsc testnet network.
and Don't forget to add the init.py file to the package


from web3 import Web3
import json
import config
import time

bsc = 'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545'
#bsc mainnet network: https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/
#bsc testnet network: https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

print(web3.is_connected())


#pancakeswap router
panRouterContractAddress = ('0xd77C2afeBf3dC665af07588BF798bd938968c72E')

#Pancake universal testnet router:0x9A082015c919AD0E47861e5Db9A1c7070E81A2C7 
#Pancake v2 router : 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E
#pancake mainnet router : 0x1A0A18AC4BECDDbd6389559687d1A73d8927E416
#universal testnet :0xd77C2afeBf3dC665af07588BF798bd938968c72E
#panabi = universal testnet router api

panabi = '[{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"permit2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"WETH9","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaportV1_5","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaportV1_4","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"openseaConduit","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"x2y2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareV2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"routerRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v2Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v3Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v3Deployer","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"v2InitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"v3InitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"stableFactory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"stableInfo","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"pancakeNFTMarket","type":"address"}],"internalType":"struct RouterParameters","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BalanceTooLow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BuyPancakeNFTFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BuyPunkFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ContractLocked","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ETHNotAccepted","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandIndex","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"message","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ExecutionFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"FromAddressIsNotOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientETH","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidBips","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandType","type":"uint256"}],"name":"InvalidCommandType","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC1155","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC721","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPoolAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPoolLength","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidReserves","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidSpender","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"LengthMismatch","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SliceOutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"StableInvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"StableTooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"StableTooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransactionDeadlinePassed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnableToClaim","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnsafeCast","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidAmountOut","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidCaller","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidSwap","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Paused","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsSent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"factory","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"info","type":"address"}],"name":"SetStableSwap","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Unpaused","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"looksRareClaim","type":"bytes"}],"name":"collectRewards","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155BatchReceived","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC721Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"pancakeV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_info","type":"address"}],"name":"setStableSwap","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"stableSwapFactory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"stableSwapInfo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'
#universal router mainnet '[{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"permit2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"weth9","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaportV1_5","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaportV1_4","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"openseaConduit","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"x2y2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareV2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"routerRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v2Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v3Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v3Deployer","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"v2InitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"v3InitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"stableFactory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"stableInfo","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"pancakeNFTMarket","type":"address"}],"internalType":"struct RouterParameters","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BalanceTooLow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BuyPancakeNFTFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BuyPunkFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ContractLocked","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ETHNotAccepted","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandIndex","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"message","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ExecutionFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"FromAddressIsNotOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientETH","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidBips","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandType","type":"uint256"}],"name":"InvalidCommandType","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC1155","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC721","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPoolAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPoolLength","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidReserves","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidSpender","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"LengthMismatch","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SliceOutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"StableInvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"StableTooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"StableTooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransactionDeadlinePassed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnableToClaim","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnsafeCast","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidAmountOut","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidCaller","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidSwap","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Paused","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsSent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"factory","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"info","type":"address"}],"name":"SetStableSwap","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Unpaused","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"looksRareClaim","type":"bytes"}],"name":"collectRewards","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155BatchReceived","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC721Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"pancakeV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_info","type":"address"}],"name":"setStableSwap","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"stableSwapFactory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"stableSwapInfo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'

senderaddress = '0x4182692466cF31f1EdbF6E06A7181CF0450F0fe6'
#the address to which the token will be sent:0x4182692466cF31f1EdbF6E06A7181CF0450F0fe6

balance = web3.eth.get_balance(senderaddress)
#print(balance)
 
humanReadable = web3.from_wei(balance,'ether')
#print(humanReadable)

tokenToBuy = web3.to_checksum_address(input("Enter TokenAddress: "))         
#Contract Address of Token we want to buy 
#web3.toChecksumAddress("0x6615a63c260be84974166a5eddff223ce292cf3d")
spend = web3.to_checksum_address('0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd')
#wbnb contract 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
#test wbnb 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd
#Example of Contract Address of the Token we want to buy cake testnet token: 0x8d008B313C1d6C7fE2982F62d32Da7507cF43551
 
#Setup the PancakeSwap contract
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=panRouterContractAddress, abi=panabi)
 

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(senderaddress)
 
start = time.time()

pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.execute(senderaddress,[spend,tokenToBuy],
#10000000000, #set to 0, or specify minimum amount of tokeny you want to receive - consider decimals!!!
#[spend,tokenToBuy],
#sender_address,
(int(time.time()) + 10000)
).build_transaction({
'from': senderaddress,
'value': web3.to_wei(0.0354829243424823411,'ether'), #This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
'gas': 250000,
'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('5','gwei'),
'nonce':nonce,
})

def monkey(private):
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(dict(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=config.private))
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    print(web3.to_hex(tx_hash) )#I'm having trouble running this last block of code
    
    #swapExactETHForTokens
    #toHex #to_hex


I am having trouble running the monkey function even though it does not give any errors.

def private():
    private_key= " "
private()



Type your wallet key in the space between the double quotes in the private_key section.


note: You may experience problems when running it with tools like pycharm, run it only with visual studio


Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a minimum reproducible-example. Please make it clear what your question is.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you never execute the monkey function?

@folengateis yes
